# app script gmail, how to search for emails which are in inbox but contain no labels

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google app script to clean up gmail.

While I know how to search for categories and labels etc, I am struggling to make a search where I can  search for emails which are 'in inbox but contain no labels'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally found the answer. I found it in documentation for [Gmail Search Operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Below is my search query, just in case you are interested:

```
in:inbox {category:social category:updates} is:unread has:nouserlabels
```

While this query search can be used in Gmail UI, the corresponding method in Apps Script is [GmailApp.search(query)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)).